# What is this Kenyan insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
This insect was seen in Nairobi, Kenya. Underside is striped black and white. What is it?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should be tagged as such and also include an estimate of the size of the organism and as much habitat information as possible. Please [edit] your post to include this information as it may be essential for a proper identification. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Perhaps a bug (Hemiptera) that is mimicing the cotton stainer bug. Might be an assassin bug.